# Javascript value inserting UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I ve a finished java/jquery and html code website. html  li items called from java code.  like

```
item: '<li><a class="C_info"></a> </li>'
};

var values = [{
name:
category:
C_info:

},
```

the matter is name category and c_info values contains a href and other codes aswell so i want to make a script to add new values to list. a simple interface with input fields and add button like offline admin panel that will change java source file on my pc not on host. like

name  input field
category  input field
c_info input field 
a href (for the a link on name value, or any kind of code change not just text ) input field.
add button

when i give values to input fields and click add it will change code like

```
item: '<li><a class="C_info"></a> </li>'
};

var values = [
{

name: 'new values given by script'
category: 'new values given by script'
C_info: 'new values given by script'

},


{

name: 'older values'
category: 'older values'
C_info: 'older values'

},
```

this way i can add new items to list easier and anyone withouh any java/html knowledge can add content . even an advice is enough. how can i make this ? java is enough, or can i do it in matlab? is it too complicated or just a simple code for java?

Comment: you want to have a function that adds name, category, and C_info to values Array?

Comment: yes a function that adds new items in array. there is more then 1 li item i want it to add new items to the list with value names (same for all) and desired input(the part i ll write for each li item). name category etc.a simple interface to add new content to list with add button and input field. like a new html page which will modify the js file on  my pc not the one on host.i ll upload the new source js file to host after.

Comment: can you have a jsfiddle of the current codes you already have? It will help us a lot. thanks.

Comment: eheh i see. :) my english is not that well. its a bit late in my time zone. i ll make it tomorrow at first :) thank you for your comments.